# pyqtgraph delete persisting legend in pyqt4 gui

Tags: python-2.7, plot, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I want to plot multiple items in a pyQt4 gui from a list selection which the user can select which plots to show. They can do this as many times as they want. Each time they plot new data, the legend persists even though the plots do not. My code is :

```
self.DataPlotter.setLabels(left=("magnitude"),bottom=(str(x_ind)))
title = str(y_ind) + " vs " + str(x_ind)
self.DataPlotter.setTitle(title)
self.DataPlotter.addLegend()

for y,c in zip(y_ind,range(len(y_ind))):
    self.DataPlotter.plot(self.df[x_ind].tolist(),self.df[y].tolist(), name=y, pen=(c,4))
```

How do I destroy the old legend each run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/DdWyB1ljQdw

I needed to add this (not sure if try/except is necessary):

```
    try:
        self.legend.scene().removeItem(self.legend)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Final code looks this:

```
        self.DataPlotter.setLabels(left=("magnitude"),bottom=(str(self.x_ind)))
        title = str(self.y_ind) + " vs " + str(self.x_ind)
        self.DataPlotter.setTitle(title)
        try:
            self.legend.scene().removeItem(self.legend)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        self.legend = self.DataPlotter.addLegend()
        for y,c in zip(y_ind,range(len(y_ind))):
           self.DataPlotter.plot(self.df[x_ind].tolist(),self.df[y].tolist(), name=y, pen=(c,4))
```